# Finding classes/files/symbols with umlauts (ä, ö, ü) by their transliteration (ae, oe, ue)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am working with code which uses German for naming of classes, symbols and files. All German special characters like ä, ü, ö and ß are used in their transliterated form, i.e. "ae" for "ä", "oe" for "ö" etc.

Since there is no technical reason for doing that anymore, I am evaluating whether allowing umlauts and the like in their natural form is feasible. The biggest problem here is that there will be inconsistent naming once using umlauts will be allowed. I.e. a class may be named "ÖffentlicheAuftragsübernahme" (new form) or "OeffentlicheAuftragsuebernahme" (old form). This will make searching for classes, symbols and files more difficult.

*Is there a way to extend the search (code navigation to be exact) of IntelliJ IDEA in a way that it will ignore whether a name is written using umlauts or their transliteration?*

I suppose, this would require modifying the way IDEA indexes files. Would that be possible with a plugin? Or is there a different way to acomplish the desired result?

### Example

Given the classes "KlasseÄ" "KlasseAe", "KlasseOe", "KlasseÜ"

IDEA "navigate to class" (CTRL+N) --> find result

- "KlasseÄ" --> ["KlasseÄ" "KlasseAe"]
- "KlasseAe" --> ["KlasseÄ" "KlasseAe"]
- "KlasseUe" --> ["KlasseÜ"]
- "KlasseÖ" --> ["KlasseOe"]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly easy to implement and does not require indexing changes. All you need to do is implement the [ChooseByNameContributor](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/navigation/ChooseByNameContributor.java) interface and register it as an extension for `gotoClassContributor` extension point. In your implementation, you can use IDEA's existing indices to find classes with the alternatively spelled names, and to return them from `getItemsByName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your own instance of `com.intellij.navigation.GotoClassContributor` and in `getItemsByName()` look for the different variants of the input name in the PSI class index.

For example, if you extend `com.intellij.ide.util.gotoByName.DefaultClassNavigationContributor`, you can implement the method like this:

```java
@Override
@NotNull
public NavigationItem[] getItemsByName(String name, final String pattern, Project project, boolean includeNonProjectItems) {
    List<NavigationItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Processor<NavigationItem> processor = Processors.cancelableCollectProcessor(result);

    List<String> variants = substituteUmlauts(name);

    for (String variant : variants) {
        processElementsWithName(variant, processor, FindSymbolParameters.wrap(pattern, project, includeNonProjectItems));
    }

    return result.isEmpty() ? NavigationItem.EMPTY_NAVIGATION_ITEM_ARRAY :
            result.toArray(new NavigationItem[result.size()]);
}
```

`substituteUmlauts()` will compute all the different versions of what you type in the search box, and all the results will be aggregated in `result`.

Comment: This does not work. In fact, "getItemsByName" will never be called when extending "DefaultClassNavigationContributor". It seems, the "ChooseByNameContributorEx" implementation is used instead when implemented.